# Development Environment - Remote local server and Git repositories

Tags: git, environment

as my main computer I'm using Windows PC. In my development I'm using my local Linux based server to host my projects. I'm also using PHPStorm as my main IDE - creating remote projects with automatic upload function enabled.

I want to start using Git as VCS - already have an account on Github and now need an advice. Where should I store my repos? On my Windows machine or on my Linux server. I'm for the second option - especially when my IDE keep uploading everything to the server but wanted to know your opinions.

How do you usually solve such issues?

Comment: Git lets you mix all three easily. Every clone is a repo in its own right.

Comment: @triplee I know, I just wondering about correct set up ;)

Comment: There tends to be less (hidden) magic in setting up a Linux server in my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first point is to decide your line endings policy, which most likely would be LF within the repos.

You would probably choose the Gihub repo as the main central repo as it will be effectively a bare repo (you won't do any work directly there).

You would need to remember to push your latest updates to your central Github repo between signing of from each system (home Windows / work Linux). In such a case you can continuously work on top of the same branch as it will be continuous.

Or, if your own machines are reachable on-line, you can actually push and pull from each of the machines, but do so on separate branches so they don't clash with each other (you can't push to a checked out branch, but you can push to other branches).

You can also carry a memory stick and use `git bundle` for maximum backup and sneaker-net capability.